# Select specific columns from table, Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a question about selecting specific columns from table using entity framework. The problem is, that I'm using `Find()` method to get my desired table, by primary key, then taking from it some data.

I have one table with massive amounts of columns and if I call `Find()` method, it will return all columns of that row, but I want to use only, for example, the data from 2 columns.

```
MyTable table = context.MyTable.Find(id); //Get MyTable object from context, id = primary key
string p1 = table.Prop1;
string p2 = table.Prop2;
```

This will return single object with all (for example it has Prop1, Prop2,...,PropN) properties filled (if its filled in database).
So I know that I can use anonymous objects or data transfer objects (DTO), but [question1] is there any other (yet simple) method to get specific columns? [question2] Is it affecting on performance if I use `Find()` (or I should use `Where()/Select()`)?

Comment: If a list of columns not known at compile time, and is only available in runtime, then you should use dynamically created queries. See [DynamicLINQ](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library), [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), [ExpressionTrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries).

Comment: They are known at the compile time.

Comment: The only difference between `Find` and let say `FirstOrDefault(condition)` is that the former first looks at the local cache and executes db query only if the object is not there. But since it (as any method which returns entity instances) will only return fully populated objects, it cannot be used for projection (`Select`) which is the *only way* to get partial data in EF.

Comment: @IvanStoev I understand that, only issue is that I want to change all `Find`s in my code to `Where/Select` (cause of performance issue), `Find` generates for example about 300 lines of `Select` code, but `Where/Select` about 10.

Comment: Then go ahead and change it. EF cannot cache partially loaded data for you. And there is no "lazy loading" for primitive data properties. Again, if EF method returns entity object, it will be fully populated. Hence you can't use `Find` and the only option is `Where` + `Select`.

Comment: @IvanStoev ok then, will do, thanks.

Comment: @IvanStoev "The only difference between..." It appears that the actual SQL sent to the server differs slightly: `FirstOrDefault` adds a `TOP (1)` command on top of a subquery, whereas `Find` just uses a `SELECT WHERE` as expected. I highly doubt this makes any practical difference whatsoever, but it may be worth noting.

Answer (score 30):

```
    var items = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                  .Select(x => new
                               {
                                    P1 = table.Prop1,
                                    P2 = table.Prop2
                               });
```

This will translate into a sql call like:

```
SELECT p.Prop1, p.Prop2 FROM mytable p WHERE p.Id = id
```

Comment: The OP has already acknowledged the option of anonymous types: _"So I know that I can use anonymous objects or data transfer objects (DTO), but [question1] is there any other (yet simple) method to get specific columns?"_ There are also quality issues with your answer, a simple code block is not sufficient.

Comment: `Find()` method returning single value (in my case), which means I can't perform `Select()` on it.

Comment: Nope, `Find()` will translate `SELECT TOP(1) * FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @id`

Comment: this answer works really well. One drawback you should be aware of is that at the time of writing this comment you can not pass anonymous objects into other functions,  so if you have a complex procedure to run, because not functions are supported in iqueryable you have no choice but to make a giant method.

Answer (score 7):

Use Data Transfer Objects:  [DTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5), which is a recommened microsoft pattern.

Putting it simple, they are just objects that hold data.

Then do like someone suggested:

```
public class MyDto
{
  public string Prop1 {get;set;} = String.Empty
  public string Prop2 {get;set;} = String.Empty
}
MyDto x = new MyDto();
 x = context.MyTable.Where(x => x.Id == id)
                  .Select(x => new MyDto
                               {
                                    P1 = table.Prop1
//I don't want prop 2, for example
                               });
```

And pass around the object. Set defaults for Auto Properties ([C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6) and up) and initialize only the properties you want.

EDIT:
I've read you don't want to use anonymous and DTO, then how you want to do it. You either use objects or anonymous.

Other ways is just build a layered structure and call the query method directly where you need it. Patterns exists for a reason.

You can call queries against [Dynamic objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects). With these you may assign fields that will be resolved at runtime, at the cost of losing strong typing.

You might also want to check if it's performance-whorty to use dynamics.

Comment: Read what OP asked: So I know that I can use anonymous objects or data transfer objects (DTO), but is there any other (yet simple) method to get specific columns?

Comment: No. There isn't. You query or use objects.

Comment: Yes, I know (or at least I think), but that does not answer OP's question :)

Comment: Actually I have given some ways to do it, but they're quite hacky.

Comment: Guys I know how to use DTO objects and Anonymous types, the problem is that I want to know does the `Find()` method affecting performance, is it slower than with dto and anonymous types, and if so is there any other methods?

Comment: Actually you can't use `dynamic` types in EF projections. EF is statically type based system.

Comment: Actually I've build myself a backend-configurable web interface in asp net mcv5 which was reading a database-persisted XML to rebuild back a web UI using dynamic and ExpandoObjects. Probabily I was putting all the queried results in a var object to make it local instead of IQueryable

Comment: Ok, so is it faster than `Find` method. I mean in cases where table have lot of columns.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to project the class back to itself, and only provide the columns you want.

```
var table = context.MyTable.Where(mt => mt.Id == id)
                           .Select(mt => new MyTable
                            {
                                Prop1 = mt.Prop1,
                                Prop2 = mt.Prop2
                            })
                           .FirstOrDefault();

string p1 = table.Prop1;
string p2 = table.Prop2;
```

Effectively, you get the strong typing of a DTO without having to create/maintain another class. All columns *not* specified will be populated with the default value of the column's type.

It translates to the following in SQL:

```
SELECT TOP(1) m.Prop1, m.Prop2 FROM MyTable m WHERE m.Id = @id
```

Which indeed gives a performance boost over `Find()` assuming you're not specifying *all* the columns.

EDIT: As Gert mentioned, use with caution, as it's not always obvious when a "partial entity" is being passed around.

Comment: It tends to cause all kinds of unexpected problems if you use "partial entities". For one, it's a constant source of ambiguity in code. Now all code has to be aware of what kind of entity it receives.

Comment: I don't know how you verified that EF Core translates that LINQ to SQL but it gives me another result, it selects all the columns and not the ones I want.

Comment: @MrDave1999 I used [.ToQueryString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.toquerystring?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions_ToQueryString_System_Linq_IQueryable_) to verify the equivalent SQL query

Comment: @MrDave1999 Did you similarly verify the SQL query or are you assuming its behavior based on the returned objects? One possibility is that your class’s properties are non-nullable (thus populate with default values) or your class’s parameter-less constructor has some prop-setting logic in it

Comment: Sorry. It does return the selected columns. It returns all columns when I use a Dto mapper. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115690/ef-core-queries-all-columns-in-sql-when-mapping-to-object-in-select

Comment: @GertArnold This is where concepts like projection objects, data transfer objects, business logic adapters etc. come into play. It must be clear that what is the required input and what is the expected output of some code, that is, accurate planning is a disproof for "now all code has to be aware of what kind of entity it receives". The projection shown above is just fine as it is.

Comment: @Kerberos I'd say that an unambiguous data contract is part of accurate planning. Even in code that's fully under my own control I wouldn't like to have to keep in mind which properties are and aren't populated when receiving entity objects. An exception to this rule is when we deliberately work with stub entities to save database roundtrips. We always try to make that really explicit in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use free `AutoMapper`'s `ProjectTo<>` extension, so the query would look like this:

```
context.OrderLines
   .Where(ol => ol.OrderId == orderId)
   .ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>(configuration)
   .ToList();
```