# EF Core: "The LINQ expression could not be translated" when using explicit casting

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, casting, dto

I have a very simple entity called `Product`. It contains an explicit casting to the DTO type `ProductListDTO`.

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string? Notes { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator ProductListDTO (Product p)
    {
        return new ProductListDTO
        {
            ID = p.ID,
            Name = p.Name,
            Description = p.Description
        };
    }
}
```

Below are 4 ways that accessed the data. One of them (Which is the desired one) fails.

**(1)** - this works

```
var allProducts = db.Products.Select(x => new ProductListDTO
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description
            }).ToList();
```

**(2)** - this also works

```
var allProducts_Casting = db.Products.Select(x => (ProductListDTO)x).ToList();
```

**(3)** - and this also works

```
var filteredProducts = db.Products.Select(x => new ProductListDTO
            {
                Name = x.Name,
                Description = x.Description
            })
                .Where(x => x.Name == "Product 1")
                .ToList();
```

**(4)** - this however does **NOT** work

```
var filteredProducts_Casting = db.Products.Select(x => (ProductListDTO) x)
            .Where(x => x.Name == "Product 1")
            .ToList();
```

The exception is:

> System.InvalidOperationException : The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => !(p.IsDeleted))
> .Where(p => ((ProductListDTO)p).Name == "Product 1")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

**Some context**

My only goal is to have a single place where I do the conversion between `Product` to `ProductListDTO` and that it can be **re-used**. And I prefer a simple approach like below.

Desired:

```
public IQueryable<ProductListDTO> OdataList()
{
    return db.Products.Select(x => (ProductListDTO)x);
}

public IQueryable<PurchaseOrderItemListDTO> OdataList()
{
    return db.PurchaseOrderItems.Select(p => new PurchaseOrderItemListDTO
                                             {
                                                 ID = p.ID,
                                                 UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                                                 Quantity = p.Quantity,
                                                 Product = (ProductListDTO) p.Product,
                                             });
}
```

But this is where I run into the problem I explained earlier

**Trying to avoid**

There's also the below approach that works fine but it's more complex and hard to explain to other developers:

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<Product, ProductListDTO>> ProductListQuery = p => new ProductListDTO
{
   ID = p.ID,
   Name = p.Name,
   Description = p.Description
};

public IQueryable<ProductListDTO> OdataList()
{
    return db.Products.Select(ProductListQuery);
}

public IQueryable<PurchaseOrderItemListDTO> OdataList()
{
    var productListing = ProductListQuery.Compile();

    return db.PurchaseOrderItems.Select(p => new PurchaseOrderItemListDTO
                                             {
                                                 ID = p.ID,
                                                 UnitPrice = p.UnitPrice,
                                                 Quantity = p.Quantity,
                                                 Product = productListing(p.Product),
                                             });
}
```

Comment: Well, this is the general `IQueryable` problem which AutoMapper and similar are trying to solve. All the "working" cases work because EF Core supports them *client* side (basically via Linq to Objects) when `Select` is the *final* operator.  When `Select` is not the final operator, then you need a custom solution.

Comment: Check [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically the problem explained here [EF Core queries all columns in SQL when mapping to object in Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115690/ef-core-queries-all-columns-in-sql-when-mapping-to-object-in-select/62138200#62138200) (and in many other places). My favorite solution (from the link) is based on [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) package and EF Core 7.0+ [LINQ query expression tree interception](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28505).

So, all you need to make desired (4) working is as follows:

1. Install the aforementioned package
2. Add the following in a code file of your choice:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class DelegateDecompilerDbContextOptionsBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder AddDelegateDecompiler(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
            => optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new DelegateDecompilerQueryPreprocessor());
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query
{
    using DelegateDecompiler;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using static ReplacingExpressionVisitor;

    public class DelegateDecompilerQueryPreprocessor :
        DecompileExpressionVisitor, IQueryExpressionInterceptor
    {
        Expression IQueryExpressionInterceptor.QueryCompilationStarting(
            Expression queryExpression, QueryExpressionEventData eventData)
            => Visit(queryExpression);

        protected override Expression VisitUnary(UnaryExpression node)
        {
            if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert && node.Method != null)
            {
                var decompiled = node.Method.Decompile();
                return Replace(decompiled.Parameters[0], Visit(node.Operand), decompiled.Body);
            }
            return base.VisitUnary(node);
        }
    }
}
```

It is the code from the linked answer extended for handling `Convert` expressions which are the expression equivalent of C# casts. The whole idea is to replace the cast with the actual code, so the EF Core query translator can "see" it, thus turning the non working case #4 into working case #3.

3. Add the following to your derived `DbContext` class `OnConfiguring` override:

```cs
optionsBuilder.AddDelegateDecompiler();
```

And that's all. Now all your casts will be translated. Enjoy :)

Comment: thank you very much for the neat solution. We've been enjoying using it ever since you answered.

I just came a cross a very interesting situation though: I have a DTO that contains other DTOs. It's 3 levels deep, and the expression visitor fails to convert the cast on the 3rd level.

I tried adding the same interceptor twice like below and got the correct behavior

`optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new DelegateDecompilerQueryPreprocessor());
 optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new DelegateDecompilerQueryPreprocessor());
`

Though this doesn't seem to be a clean solution.

Comment: Hi @AzaAsim, That's strange. Could you give me some sample model/DTOs and query which reproduces the issue? I could try creating myself, but currently I'm quite busy with my regular work.