# EF Core / .NET 6. Using an expression Select on entities

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I'm trying to implement a `Select` with an Expression to keep the object as an IQueryable and selecting into a child navigation collection

Example Code:

```
public Expression<Func<Item, ItemModel>> MapToModel =>
        Ent => new ItemModel
        {
            Id = Ent.Id,
            Name = Ent.Name,
            SKU = Ent.SKU,
            Variations = Ent.Variations == null ? default : Ent.Variations.Select(this.VariationMapper),
        };
```

With the VariationMapper being the following:

```
public Expression<Func<ItemVariation, VariationModel>> VariationMapper =>
        Ent => new VariationModel()
        {
            Id = Ent.Id,
            Name = Ent.Name,
        };
```

I receive the following error however:

> 'ICollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Select<ItemVariation, VariationModel>(IQueryable, Expression<Func<ItemVariation, VariationModel>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable'

I'm a bit perplexed as to how to resolve the issue. Or if this is even possible.  That subproperty is type `ICollection<T>` as it's a navigation property.

Comment: Also found this fantastic if tangent related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62115690/ef-core-queries-all-columns-in-sql-when-mapping-to-object-in-select/62138200#62138200

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to check for `null` for collections, EF Core will handle it. Also EF Core will not translate correctly your mapper. It needs expanding which is supplied by LINQKit.

```cs
public Expression<Func<Item, ItemModel>> MapToModel =>
        Ent => new ItemModel
        {
            Id = Ent.Id,
            Name = Ent.Name,
            SKU = Ent.SKU,
            Variations = Ent.Variations.Select(this.VariationMapper.Expand()),
        };
```

How to activate LINQKit, you can find in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66386142/10646316), along with sample how to create reusable `AsDto` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `AsQueryable`:

```cs
Variations = Ent.Variations == null 
    ? default 
    : Ent.Variations
         .AsQueryable()
         .Select(this.VariationMapper)
         .ToList()
```

Comment: This seemed to run successfully, but does it still offload that into the query for DB work rather than in memory?

For example if I later do a `.Where(x => x.Variations.All(y + y.Id > 5))` will that be projected onto the database query?

Comment: @EzraBailey there is a simple answer - check the generated SQL. EF Core allows some untranslatable custom function invocations in final projections but in this case it should generate a query.